# get a value from column based on string in another column in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like that:

```r
rrr<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5), co=c('a','b','a'))
```

```r
  a b co
1 1 3  a
2 2 4  b
3 3 5  a
```

What's the way to create a new column filled by the value from a corresponding column based on the value of `co`? So if co == 'a' then newColumn should get value from 'a' column.

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
rrr %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(newColumn = cur_data()[[co]]) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 3 × 4
      a     b co    newColumn
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1     3 a             1
2     2     4 b             4
3     3     5 a             3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)

rrr %>% 
  mutate(across(c(a,b), ~case_when(co == cur_column() ~ .), .names = 'new_{col}'),
         new_colum = coalesce(new_a, new_b), .keep="unused")
```

```
  new_a new_b new_colum
1     1    NA         1
2    NA     4         4
3     3    NA         3
```

Comment: Nice touch, I was considering this approach. Can you generalize it away from just two columns?

Comment: @r2evans. In case of more columns we could use `unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')` instead of `mutate(new_colum = coalesce(new_a, new_b), .keep="unused"`. But we have to check with an example. 
`

Answer (score 1):

### base R

In general, `[`-indexing can use a matrix for indexing, with as many columns as the original object has dimensions. While it seems odd to say it this way (since `data.frame` always has 2 dimensions), one can safely infer from this that it implicitly does `matrix`-operations on the object when doing this. It doesn't convert the original object, but it does internal casting that will result in `character` here. For instance,

```r
rrr[cbind(seq_len(nrow(rrr)), match(rrr$co, colnames(rrr)))]
# [1] "1" "4" "3"
```

Even though columns `a` and `b` are both class `numeric`, the result is cast to `character` because the internal `[`-indexing with `i=matrix(..)` is internally converting `rrr` to a `matrix`, which up-classes all columns to `character` (because of the `co` column).

We can work around this by subsetting:

```r
cols <- c("a", "b")
rrr[,cols][cbind(seq_len(nrow(rrr)), match(rrr$co, cols))]
# [1] 1 4 3
```

(And assignment with `rrr$newColumn <- ...` for either of those.)

### dplyr #1

We can adapt the above.

Note that `[`-matrix-indexing does not work on `tibble`s. There are a couple of workaround, neither of which seem "awesome" in my book:

1. Use `rrr` in the pipe. This works only so long as the original frame is just `data.frame` and not a `tibble`.
2. While we can shift to the more canonical `cur_data()` inside of the `mutate` call, we must wrap it to declass it a little.

To be safe, I'll use the second option, even though it makes the code a little less-awesome-looking.

```r
library(dplyr)
rrr %>%
  mutate(newColumn = as.numeric(as.data.frame(cur_data())[cbind(row_number(), match(co, names(rrr)))]))
#   a b co newColumn
# 1 1 3  a         1
# 2 2 4  b         4
# 3 3 5  a         3
```

### dplyr #2

We can generalize TarJae's suggestion a bit with

```r
library(dplyr)
rrr %>%
  mutate(newColumn = apply(across(a:b, ~ case_when(co == cur_column() ~ .)),
                           1, function(z) na.omit(z)[1]))
#   a b co newColumn
# 1 1 3  a         1
# 2 2 4  b         4
# 3 3 5  a         3
```

A notable side-effect of this is that it preserves the desired `numeric` class of the columns (as can be seen with `str` or such).

(While a code-golf approach might reduce it from `apply(.., 1, function(z) na.omit(z)[1])` to `apply(.., 1, na.omit)`, the latter can fail: if `co` includes something not found in the other columns, then the call to `na.omit` will return a length-0 vector, which will not work. By using `na.omit(z)[1]`, the `[1]` will force it to `NA` in that case.)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution in `base R`:

```r
rrr$newColumn <- apply(rrr, 1, \(x) as.numeric(x[x["co"]]))
rrr

#>   a b co newColumn
#> 1 1 3  a         1
#> 2 2 4  b         4
#> 3 3 5  a         3
```

Comment: FYI, the reason `as.numeric` is needed here is related to the comment in my answer about the whole frame being up-cast to `character`. The `apply` function converts its first argument to a matrix internally.

Comment: Thanks for having commented my solution, @r2evans! Actually, `as.numeric` is not necessary -- it was initially needed when I was assigning the new column to column `co`.

Comment: I'm inferring that it is necessary, though, since your `newColumn` is a different class from the source columns.

Comment: Please, try my code -- you will be convinced that `as.numeric` is not neeeded, @r2evans! :-)

Comment: Nope. `identical(class(rrr$a), class(apply(rrr, 1, \(x) x[x["co"]])))` is false.

Comment: You are right, @r2evans! `rrr$newColumn` is character type -- therefore, `as.numeric` is needed. Thanks to let me know that!